# Interpolating an argument into a variable name

Tags: ruby, interpolation

I have several pages where a date is input. I want to capture the day, month and year and store them to be checked later on. Each page has its own unique ID but uses the same IDs for each field: day, month and year.

I've got this on each page where the date is captured at the moment:

```
  @page_10_day = find(:id, 'day').value
  @page_10_month = find(:id, 'month').value
  @page_10_year = find(:id, 'year').value
```

But I'd like to do something like this:

`capture_date("page_10")`

```
def capture_date(page)
  @"#{page}_day" = find(:id, 'day').value
  @"#{page}_month" = find(:id, 'month').value
  @"#{page}_year" = find(:id, 'year').value
  end
```

Is there a way of just having one method to capture the date and naming objects using an argument?

Comment: Instead of creating dynamic variables like this, use a hash with dynamic keys. Something like `@dates[page][:day] = find(:id, 'day').value`

Comment: you're looking for an `instance_variable_set` method.

Comment: Ilya is right that you can do it using `instance_variable_set`, but Sergio is right that you probably shouldn't be creating instance variables at runtime. this seems like the perfect situation for a hash. is there any reason you don't want to use a hash?

Comment: Only reason for not using a hash is I hadn't thought of it :-) Thanks, @SergioTulentsev